# Row variable indexing and creating a new data frame

Tags: r

I have a data like 
[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vH8Rs.png)I want to create a new data frames each for  players along with their corresponding variables in R programming?

Comment: Try with `split` i.e. ` split(df1, df1$X)`

Comment: please help me in creating a new data frame for each player.do we need to consider doing indexing

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.